# Deploying java application in jboss application server

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have a java application which I was running using tomcat server. Now I need to run the same application in jboss server.I am new to jboss, I tried deploying war file in jboss but not able to do so.

I don't know what changes needs to be done for application to run on jboss.
Any one please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Which exception are you getting, did you add libs\JNDI reference\properties to your tomcat? Usually dropping it in the deploy folder does the trick

Comment: Appliation works fine with tomcat. Now I want same application to run with jboss.

Comment: that's not answering my questions, we know it works on Tomcat you said so. But we need more information on the error you get and if there's any configuration you had to do on Tomcat for your application. It might also just be a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious answer would be Read The Friendly Manual.

You can configure JBoss to autodeploy files in the `standalone/deployed/` directory for example, you can also use the maven-jboss7 plugin to handle deployment from maven.

I'm sure the jboss community forums have plenty of examples.